# Gstreamer: gstreamer can't find avdec_h264, brew can't install gst-libav anymore

Tags: macos, homebrew, gstreamer

On macOS 14.0.

I have a pipeline with avdec_h264 and gstreamer can't find it. According to Gstreamer's website, it's part of gst-libav.
when I try to do brew install gst-libav, I get this:

```
Warning: gstreamer 1.22.6_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.22.6_1, run:
  brew reinstall gstreamer
```

Checking on Homebrew's website I see this package is now gone, and on gstreamer's package, it says all gst- plugins should be bundled. Then why is avdec_h264 not there?

Is there a binary I can download of this plugin to put in the plugin folder, or a way to force installation of gst-libav? Or another solution?

Comment: Is ffmpeg installed ?

Comment: brew says ffmpeg 6.0_1 is installed, so yes.

Comment: Have you tried using x264enc ?

Comment: As for my own answer to my question, decodebin worked. openh264dec was also reported to work, but I didn’t try it myself.

Answer (score 1):

`gst-*` plugins merged into `gstreamer` in [this PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/125996) on April 13 this year, which means, `gstreamer` would also install [gst-* plugins](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/g/gstreamer.rb#L109), that is why there are no separate `gst-*` formulae.

Comment: Great, but I'm now on two different computers that can't find  avdec_h264. Why is this happening? If we can't install libav, how to get an h264 decoder?

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't solve the underlying problem, if you can't find avdec_h264 and you need it for decoding, decodebin can be used in its place and it will find the right available decoder.